# How to stabilize a pergola

Tags: structural

I am building a pergola but have no way of sinking the posts into the ground.

I have drilled a steel bar into the ground about 8" and the same up into the 4 post which are 8"×8" 7 feet tall.

Will this be enough to stabilize it or do i need any more support to stop it from leaning over.

Comment: Will the legs be diagonally braced to the roof?

Comment: I agree with whatsisname there will need to be multiple braces to keep the posts from twisting in the wind.

Comment: How big is the pergola?

Comment: Even pergola's with Properly installed posts need to have bracing to prevent racking back and forth or (*"leaning over*")

Comment: Please post photos or describe your design in detail. It's difficult to answer well without more information.

Comment: Voting to close. We need more design details. OP hasn't been back.

Comment: The most important item here is "steel bar into the ground about 8 **inches**". 8 inches isn't enough to stabilize _anything_ 7' tall, no matter how much diagonal bracing there is up top.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you will still have rocking and the holes in the wood posts will widen.

I would recommend some post supports similar to the one shown below, anchored into the concrete with lag shields and lag screws and to the posts with lag screws.

[image]

You will also need some braces from the posts to the joists.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvote. This might be the first time I've seen a post base suggested that actually appears to be intended to hold up a post. These could work.